# A Fisher information metric which doesn't refer to any exponential family

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fisher-information, information-geometry

If $\mathcal E$ is some exponential family of distributions, then we can view it as a Riemannian manifold with local metric the Fisher information matrix. We can then define the Fisher metric: the distance between p and q is simply the length of the (shortest) geodesic between p and q (if I'm not mistaken, there is actually a single geodesic linking p and q but I'm not sure)

If we now consider $\mathcal E_2$, a second exponential family, which contains $\mathcal E$ then we have a second manifold, and we change the Fisher metric because we now have new, potentially shorter, paths we could take to go from p to q.

My question is on whether we can construct bigger and bigger exponential families until we contain all probability distributions. We would then have an asymptotic Fisher metric, and have endowed the space of probability distributions with a Riemannian manifold structure

1. Is such a construction possible ? One problem I see is that, if p and q are in the same exponential family, then they need to have the same support
2. If it's not really possible, are there interesting sub-classes of probability distributions which we can turn into Riemannian manifolds ?

Comment: (1) There are examples on this site of non-exponential families. That would seem to answer your first question in the negative. (2) A Riemannian manifold is, by definition, finite-dimensional. That answers (in the negative) another speculation. (3) In your last question, what do you mean by "interesting"?